# Why sum and count give me unexpected results while using influxdb v.013

Tags: influxdb

I'm not able to figure out how `sum` and `count` works. I'm using influxdb with version 0.13.

Let's say I've a time measurement with lots of data and first let me query it to get 10 rows:

`> select count from X where time > 1472807400000000000 LIMIT 10`

will respond with:

```
name: (X)
-------------------------
time                    count
1472807580000000000     1
1472807640000000000     1
1472807640000000000     1
1472807650000000000     3
1472807660000000000     1
1472807660000000000     6
1472807670000000000     1
1472807670000000000     3
1472807680000000000     1
1472807680000000000     1
```

Now I will sum this column:

`> select sum(count)  from X where time > 1472807400000000000 LIMIT 10`

```
name: X
-------------------------
time                    sum
1472807400000000001     102
```

and count this column:

`> select count(count)  from X where time > 1472807400000000000 LIMIT 10`

```
name: X
-------------------------
time                    count
1472807400000000001     44
```

### What I was expecting

"count - Returns the number of non-null values in a single field"
shouldn't that be `10` ?

"sum - Returns the sum of the all values in a single field."
shouldn't that be value close to `19` ?(1,1,1,3,1,6,1,3,1,1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `LIMIT` clause limits the number of results that are returned. Any function call takes precedence.

So

```
select sum(count)  from X where time > 1472807400000000000 LIMIT 10
```

is functionally equivalent to

```
select sum(count)  from X where time > 1472807400000000000
```

Similarly

```
select count(count)  from X where time > 1472807400000000000 LIMIT 10
```

is functionally equivalent to

```
select count(count)  from X where time > 1472807400000000000
```